# Is it true that $x\notin (B−C) \leftrightarrow x\notin B \wedge x\notin C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Came across this expansion. Is it true? Maybe someone can prove it too.

Comment: Equals signs should only be used for equality.  Do you mean to ask if $x\notin (B-C)\Leftrightarrow x\notin B \wedge x\notin C$?  Can you think of a reason why $x$ might not be an element of the LHS?

Comment: If $x\not\in B\land x\not\in C$, then certainly $x\not\in B\setminus C$. However, we can have $x\not\in B\setminus C$ and have $x\in C$. For example, let $B$ be the set of natural numbers, and $C$ the set of even natural numbers. Then $4\not\in B\setminus C$ but $4\in C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct implication is:

$$x\notin (B-C) \Leftrightarrow x\notin B \vee x\in C$$

This can be seen from negating the *definition* of set differences:

$$x\in (B-C)\Leftrightarrow x\in B \wedge x\notin C$$

Now, knowing this, you can construct a counterexample to your proposed statement.

> For example, if $x\in C$